# VS-Code own language extension

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of writing an extension for vs code that supports my own language. I want a string to start after a certain character, here a `=`.

My code looks like this:

```
"strings": {

        "name": "string.quoted.double.hdbtextbundle",
        "begin": "=",
        "end": "\\n",
```

Comment: Have you tried anything by now?

Comment: so this is my only problem :D I just want that the string begins after the "=". At the moment the "=" is also colored.

Comment: I have solved my problem with a RegEx.